# Copy Website to new Directory

Tags: .htaccess

I have a rather large website that I need to move to a different directory.  Right now, the website has a normal structure.

www.technology.com

The company wants the entire website moved so the new main URL will be:

www.technology.com/structure

So, the current page structure which is:

```
www.technology.com
www.technology.com/about
www.technology.com/services
www.technolgy.com/products
```

needs to become:

```
www.technology.com/structure
www.technology.com/structure/about
www.technology.com/structure/services
www.technolgy.com/structure/products
```

This is an older website that isn't inside of a CMS.  Would the easiest way to do this be to actually just create a directory in the root called **structure** and copy everything into it?

What would I do as far as catching any people that might have links bookmarked?  So, if someone were to come to www.technology.com, I would want them to automatically be redirected to > www.technology.com/structure and vice-versa with everything else.  I'm assuming this could be accomplished with the .htaccess file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you must move it or you only want to change url to include structure?

Comment: please provide you htaccess file here in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is right just move your complete website to `www.technology.com/structure` and put this in to your .htaccess file in `www.technology.com/`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?structure(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /structure/$1 [R=301,L]
```

One remark: The whole thing would only work if on your apache server mod_rewrite is enabled and you are allowed to use htaccess files (with mod_rewrite), this is not always the case by default.

Comment: I tried this and am getting a 500 Error.  mod_rewrite is available on my server.  Any suggestions?

Comment: /var/www/html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewiteRule', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: I fixed the type, and I'm no longer getting a 500 error, but the rewrite isn't happening either.